# Map Visualization with former countries

Tags: powerbi

I'm doing some Power BI with record releases. I would like to display release country on a map, but for Germany I have a problem: I would like to display West and East Germany and the re-united Germany. And how do I deal with Yugoslavia?

Comment: "And how do I deal with Yugoslavia?" possibly the best example ever seen of "too broad"